# Angular select-option - populate drop down list with values from Array of object

Tags: angular, user-interface, hashmap

I am trying to fetch values for the drop down list box from a array of object:

My map looks like this which is of the form: Map. Key is a string and a value is an array object. I want to pick an attribute from the object and populate the drop down list like:

```
List -> instance1 
        instance2
```

```
  {"myservice":[
     {
        "selector":"instance1",
        "selected":true
     },
     {
        "selector":"instance2",
        "selected":false
     }
  ]}
```

Here is what i tried:

```
   <table>
      <tr *ngFor="let myMap of sdata.sdMap | keyvalue">
        <td>{{myMap.key}}</td>
        <td>
        <select ng-options="serviceDetail as serviceDetail.selector for serviceDetail in myMap.value" ng-model="selected"></select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

This does not populate the dropdown list with instance1, instance2 however. What could be wrong?

Comment: Version of Angular? you say it is AngularJS, but you're using *ngFor that's Angular directive.

Comment: The version is 9.1.9